# Circular dependency In Liferay Studio

Tags: java, liferay-7.3

An error occur when I'm fetch the data with the database so how to solve this problem

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Circular dependency between the following tasks:
  :modules:amfregistration:amfregistration-api:classes
  --- :modules:amfregistration:amfregistration-api:compileJava
  --- :modules:amfregistration:amfregistration-api:jar
  +--- :modules:amfregistration:amfregistration-api:classes (*)
  --- :modules:amfregistration:amfregistration-api:jar (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you created a gradle task that depends on some other task. But be it directly or indirectly, the other task requires this task as a dependency. Gradle cannot figure out where to start building.

Check the three listed tasks, focusing on their dependencies. Remove as much as possible. If that does not work out, maybe you have to redesign your build structure.